# Sorting on multiple values MYSQL Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, laravel

I'm currently working on a project where I need to sort a collection using MySQL, but I really can't get this working. I have a table with Components. Components belong to a Training. So a Training can have multiple Components.

I made a HTML table with the results, with the following columns:

- Date
- Time
- Training_id
- Component

What I want, is to sort the components by:
- Date, all dates should be sorted ASC
- Time, the component that has the earliest time needs to be on top
- Component, based on the Time, Components needs te be grouped by the same Training.

For example, a list with these components:

Date: 4-11-2014
Time: 11:00
Training_id: 1
Component: First component

Date: 4-11-2014
Time: 11:30
Training_id: 2
Component: First component of training_id 2

Date: 4-11-2014
Time: 12:00
Training_id: 1
Component: Second component

Needs to be placed in the order: First component, second component, First component of training_id 2. This because the first component based on time is 'First component'. The next step is that all components for this Training will be sorted underneath the 'First Component' (and also based on the time). After that The next training comes.

Does anyone have a clue, I really can't figure this one out..

This is the order_by functions I have so far:

```
    $result =  Components::ofType('Training')
        ->select('components.*')
        ->join('trainings', 'trainings.id', '=', 'components.parent_id')
        ->groupBy('components.id')
        ->orderBy('component_start_date')
        ->orderBy('parent_id')
        ->orderBy('from')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's may work for you
    $data->orderBy("date","asc")
         ->orderBy("time","asc")

Comment: Thanks, the only thing that I miss here is that components of the same training will be displayed below each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
$training = DB::table('training')
                        ->leftJoin("component", "component.training_id", "=", "training.id")
                        ->groupBy("trainig.id")
                        ->orderBy("component.Date", "asc")->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will only sort on date, I have to sort on the date of the component, parent and the time.